# Is there any point in using image_transport republish instead of using CompressedImage in Python?

Tags: opencv, sensor-msgs, rospy, compressedimage, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Python ROS node that subscribes to a topic of message type CompressedImage. So far it works fine (I play a rosbag with compressed images, run my node, and it correctly reads them [I checked using cv2.imshow()].

I'm probably misunderstanding what the point of compressed_image_transport is. If I have a ROS node (say usb_cam) publishing compressed image messages, and my Python node subscribes to those compressed images (specifying sensor_msgs.msg.CompressedImage as the message type), why would I ever need image_transport or republish for my node (I know it's being used in the publishing node, i.e. usb_cam).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195939/is-there-any-point-in-using-image_transport-republish-instead-of-using-compressedimage-in-python?/) by [basheersubei](https://answers.ros.org/users/7676/basheersubei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-10-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is a bit late, but in my case it was more convenient to migrate from input data type Images to CompressedImages using republish. This way, I did not have to modify code which stated in multiple occasions the incoming message type as sensor_msgs::Image.

---

Originally posted by [Tommi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23616/tommi/) with karma: 111 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1